# How do I permanently install rEFInd onto my mac from Ubuntu (without using mac os)

Tags: boot, uefi, mac, refind

I deleted my mac os and I had trouble getting my mac to recognize the Ubuntu installer when i pressed the alt key on boot. I had to re-install mac os install refind and then install Ubuntu again when it was recognized and delete mac os. How do I permanently install rEFInd so that if I do an encrypted install or wiped the drive I could still use rEFInd? All of this from Ubuntu (I don't want to reinstall mac os again).

EDIT:

Here are the errors I found when I tried to change bootmgr error:
I tried doing a manual install to `EFI/BOOT.bootx64.efi` and it worked I think but I had some errors when I tried changing boot order:

```
raj@raj-MacBookPro:~$ sudo efibootmgr -c -l \\EFI\\refind\\refind_x64.efi -L rEFInd  
[sudo] password for raj:   
** Warning ** : Boot0002 has same label rEFInd  
** Warning ** : Boot0003 has same label rEFInd  
BootCurrent: 0000  
Timeout: 5 seconds  
BootOrder: 0004,0003,0002,0000,0080,0001
Boot0000* ubuntu  
Boot0001* rEFInd Boot Manager  
Boot0002* rEFInd  
Boot0003* rEFInd  
Boot0080* Mac OS X  
Boot0081* Mac OS X  
Boot0082*   
BootD1A6* AST  
BootFFFF* 
Boot0004* rEFInd  
raj@raj-MacBookPro:~$ efibootmgr -o 0001,0080,0081  

boot entry 1 does not exist  

raj@raj-MacBookPro:~$
```

I've tried many other versions of the `efibootmgr` command such as `efibootmgr -o 1,80,81` but they haven't worked.

Answer (score 2):

Three options occur to me:

1. Use the Linux port of the `bless` utility. This is now available in the Ubuntu archives (at least for 14.04), but I'm not sure when it was added. I have yet to properly document this in the rEFInd documentation, but it's on my list of things to do.
2. Install rEFInd on the ESP using the fallback filename of `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` (or `EFI/BOOT/bootia32.efi` for older Macs with 32-bit EFIs). Most Macs will honor this filename if they can't find something else to boot, but I can't make promises about any specific model.
3. Using an OS X live CD or USB flash drive (like an installation disc). You can launch a Terminal in such a disc, and that should enable you to run rEFInd's `install.sh` in OS X. You'd need to use the `--esp` or `--ownhfs {device-id}` option to `install.sh`, though.

Comment: I tried installing refind manually to the  EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi, but I had errors changing boot order which I posted above.

Comment: What do I do to change boot manager correctly? I've also tried to see if rEFInd shows up if I hit ALT on boot.